# connection issue with hazelcast on amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast v3.6 on two amazon AWS virtual machines (not using the AWS specific settings for hazelcast).  The connection is supposed to work via TCP/IP connection settings (not multicasting). I have opened 5701-5801 address for connection on the virtual machines.
I have tried using iperf on the two virtual machines using which I can see that the client on one VM connects to the server on another VM (and vice versa when I switch the client server setup for iperf).

When I launch two Hazelcast servers on different VM's, the connection is not established.  The log statements and the hazelcast.xml config are given below (I am not using the programmatic settings for Hazelcast).   I have changed the IP addresses below:

```
20160401-16:41:02.812 [cached2] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connecting to /22.23.24.25:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
20160401-16:41:02.812 [cached3] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connecting to /22.23.24.25:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
20160401-16:41:02.813 [cached1] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connecting to /22.23.24.25:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
20160401-16:41:02.816 [cached1] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Could not connect to: /22.23.24.25:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /22.23.24.25:570
2]
20160401-16:41:02.816 [cached1] TcpIpJoiner INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Address[22.23.24.25]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
20160401-16:41:02.817 [cached3] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Could not connect to: /22.23.24.25:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /22.23.24.25:570
3]
20160401-16:41:02.817 [cached3] TcpIpJoiner INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Address[22.23.24.25]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
20160401-16:41:02.834 [cached2] TcpIpConnectionManager INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Established socket connection between /45.46.47.48:51965 and /22.23.24.25:5701
20160401-16:41:02.849 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0] TcpIpConnection INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connection [Address[22.23.24.25]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket 
closed!]
20160401-16:41:02.851 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0] NonBlockingSocketReader WARN - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[54.89.161.2
28]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
20160401-16:41:03.692 [cached2] InitConnectionTask INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connecting to /22.23.24.25:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
20160401-16:41:03.693 [cached2] TcpIpConnectionManager INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Established socket connection between /45.46.47.48:60733 and /22.23.24.25:5701
20160401-16:41:03.696 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-1] TcpIpConnection INFO - [45.46.47.48]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connection [Address[22.23.24.25]:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket 
closed!]
```

**Part of Hazelcast config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>abc</name>
        <password>defg</password>
    </group>

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0-5900</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <!--<multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>-->
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>22.23.24.25</member> 
             </tcp-ip>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="true">
            <interface>45.46.47.48</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false" />
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
            <password>thepass</password>
            <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>

    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
```

**iperf server and client log statements**

```
Server listening on TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 22.23.24.25, TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 1.33 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 172.31.17.104 port 57398 connected with 22.23.24.25 port 5701
[  4] local 172.31.17.104 port 5701 connected with 22.23.24.25 port 55589
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   662 MBytes   555 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   797 MBytes   666 Mbits/sec


Server listening on TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local xxx.xx.xxx.xx port 5701 connected with 22.23.24.25 port 57398
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 22.23.24.25, TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 1.62 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  6] local 172.31.17.23 port 55589 connected with 22.23.24.25 port 5701
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  6]  0.0-10.0 sec   797 MBytes   669 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   662 MBytes   553 Mbits/sec
```

Note:
I forgot to mention that I can connect from hazelcast client to server i.e. when I use a hazelcast client to connect to a single hazlecast server node, I am able to connect just fine

Comment: I think you hit this issue: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7895

Comment: @noctarius danke - since you work at hazeclast, perhaps you can confirm which port range I need to open in my security settings.  I already have  
5701-5801 open.  Any idea which additional range I should open?  Your response will beat my wireshark experiments :)

Comment: You should be fine by opening 5701 (if there's just one node on each machine), obviously output port is randomly chosen but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I have tried opening 5701-5801 but that has not resolved the issue.  It could just be my configuration (for hazelcast) - I am trying to rule that out.  I will update the post once I make progress.

Comment: just try to remove the "outbound-port" configuration as this is not working at the moment. Best is to just remove EVERYTHING from the config that you don't use or have changed. It pretty much keeps join config and group config.

Comment: resolved - will update.  I opened more ports and changed config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An outbound ports range which includes 0 is interpreted by hazelcast as "use ephemeral ports", so the `<outbound-ports>` element has actually no effect in your configuration. There is an associated test in hazelcast sources: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/75251c4f01d131a9624fc3d0c4190de5cdf7d93a/hazelcast/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/nio/NodeIOServiceTest.java#L60

Comment: thank you - yes, I modified the outbound port range, added the range to the aws firewall setup and was able to get the setup working.